# Where are the Express Editions of Visual Studio 2012 after 2013 is released?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-express

After Microsoft has released Visual Studio 2013, the download links to Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web (and all 2012 Express for that matter) have vanished from their site.

They have still kept download links to Visual Studio 2010 Express. This seems ridiculous. I have a system where I would like to do some testing without IE 10 installed which is a prereq for Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web. Only Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web allows that.

If anyone knows where I could find the legit ISO for VS 2012 Express for Web, it would be of great help! I believe express editions are completely free forever, so getting an ISO would be legit.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a link locator or referral service. Questions asking for recommendations for or locations of off-site resources are inappropriate here. The [help] pages have information about the types of questions that are (and are not) proper to ask here. Please take a few minutes to review them. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft is notorious for changing removing links from their portal :)
Here is the actual link:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30669

Hope this helps.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a link locator or referral service. Please do not answer clearly off-topic questions. It encourages more off-topic questions. If you're not sure what the guidelines are for questions here, the [help] pages can clarify them for you. Thanks.